# WSO 2 AM User Management API

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I'm currently building an app that consume data from WSO2AM Restful API. I'm using WSO2AM 2.1.0

From what I see from https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Publisher+APIs, there is no API end point for User Management, and the thing is I need that one.

So after doing some google, I found this https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Managing+Users+and+Roles+with+APIs but in that link it's clearly says that it's for WSO2IS

My questions are:

1. Is there available user management API for WSO2AM (doesn't matter if it's Restful or SOAP-WSDL)
2. Is this WSO2IS user management API can be used on the WSO2AM ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All WSO2 products are built on a single platform, therefore components of each product are mixed in other products such as user management component is used by all of the WSO2 products even though it is developed as an identity component. Hence you can use the following steps to access the user management soap service in WSO2 API Manager.

1. Set the "HideAdminServiceWSDLs" element to "false" in /repository/conf/carbon.xml file.
2. Restart the API Manager Server.
3. If you have started the server in default configurations, use the following URL in your browser to see the WSDL of the admin service: https://localhost:9443/services/RemoteUserStoreManagerService?wsdl.